# Nutch 2.2.1 build stuck issue

Tags: java, ant, ivy, nutch

I am having issues building Nutch 2.2.1 behind my company firewall. My build gets stuck here:

```
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = ~/nutchtest/nutch/ivy/ivysettings.xml
```

When I contacted the hosting admin, they said - "Ant is trying to download files from internet and it will have problems with our firewalls. You will either have to download the files yourself and then scp/sftp them to the machine. Unfortunately we don't have an http proxy."

From further digging, I could see Ant is trying to access this link http://ant.apache.org/ivy/. Could anyone please advise what I should do to make Ant compile Nutch without accessing the internet? I can download required files from http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ and scp/sftp to the server but I am not sure what files to download and where to put them?

Comment: I would say, add the entry: `ant.apache.org    localhost` in the file `/etc/hosts`, run a `httpd server` on your machine and put the packages in the correct directories. Basically, fool ant into thinking that it is downloading from internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the build on a machine connected to the internet. Ivy will cache your build's dependencies here (by default):

```
$HOME/.ivy2/cache
```

A populated cache will enable you to repeat the build inside your firewall.

I would also suggest enhancing the build to run the ivy [report](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) task. This will produce webpage listing the dependency tree. If you want to build a local repository this information is very useful.

Finally consider running a repository manager inside your firewall. Tools like Nexus and Artifactory make repository hosting a lot simpler to manage. Consider obtaining a firewall exception for this server. Repository managers are used to cache useful internet repositories like Maven Central.

Comment: Hi Mark! Your response is very helpful! Does it necessary to run the ivy report task as park of Nutch compilation?

Comment: @sunskin Not necessary, just very useful in order to determine what depends on what.

Comment: Thanks Mark! The cache that was build on a machine connected to the internet have some files with filenames ending with hostname of that machine. Should I change the filenames of such files to match the hostname of the server I will be updloading those files to? IS there any better way of doing that?

Comment: @sunskin I would just copy the cache and see if it works. This is supposed to be a quick and dirty solution to your problem.

Comment: It did actually! Thanks Mark